# What are some C++ alternatives to static objects that could make destruction safer (or more deterministic)?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, static, destructor, raii

I'm working on a large code base that, for performance reasons, limits access to one or more resources. A thread pool is a good analogy to my problem - we don't want everyone in the process spinning up their own threads, so a common pool with a producer/consumer job queue exists in an attempt to limit the number of threads running at any given time.

There isn't an elegant way to make ownership of the thread pool clear so, for all intents and purposes, it is a singleton. I speak better in code than in English, so here is an example:

```
class ThreadPool {
public:
  static void SubmitTask(Task&& t) { instance_.SubmitTask(std::move(t)); }

private:
  ~ThreadPool() {
    std::for_each(pool_.begin(), pool_.end(), [](auto &t) {
      if (t.joinable()) t.join();
    });
  }

private:
  std::array<std::thread, 5> pool_;
  static ThreadPool instance_; // here or anonymous namespace
};
```

The issue with this pattern is `instance_` doesn't go out of scope until after main has returned which typically results in races or crashes. Also, keep in mind this is analogous to my problem so better ways to do something asynchronously isn't really what I'm after; just better ways to manage the lifecycle of static objects.

Alternatives I've thought of:

1. Provide an explicit `Terminate` function that must be called manually before leaving main.
2. Not using statics at all and leaving it up to the app to ensure only a single instance exists.
3. Not using statics at all and crashing the app if more than 1 instance is instantiated.

I also realize that a small, sharp, team could probably make the above code work just fine. However, this code lives within a large organization that has many developers of various skill levels contributing to it.

Comment: Don't (ever) try to do too much in a destructor, that's the best advice I can give you.

Comment: Even more fun: There can be a window before `instance_` is constructed during which `SubmitTask` can be called. Be cautious and it's better if you never go here at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly bind the lifetime to your main function. Either add a static `shutdown()` method to your `ThreadPool` that does any cleanup you need and call it at the end of `main()`.

Or fully bind the lifetime via RAII:

```cpp
class ThreadPool {
public:
  static ThreadPool* get() { return instance_.get(); }

  void SubmitTask(Task&& t) { ... }
  ~ThreadPool() { ... }

private:
  ThreadPool() {}

  static inline std::unique_ptr<ThreadPool> instance_;

  friend class ThreadPoolScope;
};

class ThreadPoolScope  {
public:
  ThreadPoolScope(){
    assert(!ThreadPool::instance_);
    ThreadPool::instance_.reset(new ThreadPool());
  }

  ~ThreadPoolScope(){
    ThreadPool::instance_.reset();
  }
};

int main() {
  ThreadPoolScope thread_pool_scope{};
  ...
}

void some_func() {
  ThreadPool::get()->SubmitTask(...);
}
```

This makes destruction completely deterministic and if you do this with multiple objects, they are automatically destroyed in the correct order.

Comment: This is probably a solid approach - could still provide access to the instance statically (essentially a scooped global variable).

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I think I just personally like the `get()` pattern, because it doesn't make the exact storage method part of the interface.